# Pandas: rank() under groupby() returns "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
index, col_name, extra_col
1, item_1, stuff
2, item_2, stuff
3, item_3, stuff
4, item_4, stuff
5, item_5, stuff
6, item_6, stuff
7, item_7, stuff
8, item_8, stuff
9, item_9, stuff
```

on which I'm applying the following transformation:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = 'col_name')
df['yPos'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 3
df['xPos'] = df.groupby(["yPos"]).rank(method='first')-1
df = df.astype({'x': 'int'})
```

I want to add two columns to my dataframe `xPos` and `yPos`. `yPos` column is working fine. however I have the following error when running the line with the `xPos` column:

`Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

What's wrong?

Comment: Not reproducible, `response` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produced results of multiple columns when you attempt to assign it to one column `xPos`.  Hence, the error.  You can instead rank only on `yPos` to get the relative serial number in `xPos`.

Change your codes as follows:

```
df = df.sort_values(by = 'col_name')
df['yPos'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 3

df['xPos'] = df.groupby("yPos")['yPos'].rank(method='first')-1
df = df.astype({'xPos': int})
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   index col_name extra_col  yPos  xPos
0      1   item_1     stuff     0     0
1      2   item_2     stuff     0     1
2      3   item_3     stuff     0     2
3      4   item_4     stuff     1     0
4      5   item_5     stuff     1     1
5      6   item_6     stuff     1     2
6      7   item_7     stuff     2     0
7      8   item_8     stuff     2     1
8      9   item_9     stuff     2     2
```

Comment: so adding `['yPos']` is always required? Or only in specific context?

Comment: @SimonBreton Not always required, but if you want to assign it to one column, you need to.

Comment: @SimonBreton  `Groupby.Rank()` can rank multiple columns and give results of multiple columns.  But if you want only to rank base on `yPos` and produce the result in also one column `xPos`, you have to specify the column that you want to rank. This is the logics.